# Visual Studio - Not Pulling all Columns Back from Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012, stored-procedures

The issue I am having is this:

I have written several SQL stored procedures into my database to be used by my application. I tested the procedures in Toad and they pull back the data correctly. However, when I attempt to call the stored procedures in Visual Studio, they run without error except they only return the primary key column.

For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [schemaName].GetSiteByName @siteName varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT SiteID, SiteName, CreatedBy, CreateDate
    FROM SitesTable
    WHERE SiteName LIKE '%' + @siteName + '%'
END
```

The data that I get back when running this procedure in Toad appears like this when searching for 'hall':

```
SiteID     SiteName     CreatedBy     CreateDate
------------------------------------------------------
1          hall01       Developer     2014-08-09
2          hall02       Developer     2014-08-10
13         hall03       Developer     2014-08-10
14         hall04       Developer     2014-08-10
15         hall05       Developer     2014-08-12
```

In Visual Studio this is all it returns:

```
SiteID     
------------------------------------------------------
1          
2          
13          
14          
15
```

I've checked to ensure the application/user has permission to pull the data (At this point I have logged in as the db owner). I have also attempted simple select statements which pull all the data from a table and the same issue occurs. Finally, I have written the same queries using Visual Studio and it pulls the data back just fine with all the columns included; it only seems to lose the columns when the query is embedded in a stored procedure.

Comment: What do you mean, "in Visual Studio"?

Comment: I suppose it wasn't all that clear, sorry. What I mean by "in Visual Studio" is that I am executing the query through the server explorer. I right click on the store precdure and select execute. 

Also, when I run the query with my Hydrator I get an error telling me it's pulling back a null.